# How to run integration task after run task in gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

***My Application is Spring boot application exposing some rest api***

To run  my integration tests , , first the application need to be up and running , as my application gradle based , how to make sure when i execute  gradle command from command prompt , first application run and the integration tests will run .

```
task integration(type: Test, description: 'Runs the integration tests.', group: 'Verification') {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

task appRunAndIntegrtationTest {
    dependsOn 'run'
    dependsOn 'integration'
    tasks.findByName('integration').mustRunAfter 'run'
}
```

i added above code to build.gradle , but application up and running , thats it , it stayed their only , integration tests are not running , can anyone has idea on this please .

update : @Strelok , as mentioned , the application started up and integration task is not running .

update 1 : i found one gradle plugin

***https://github.com/marc0der/gradle-spawn-plugin***

i am trying to use like below

```
task startServer(type: SpawnProcessTask, dependsOn: 'assemble') {
    command "java -jar ${projectDir}/build/libs/example.jar"
    ready 'Started Application'
}

task stopServer(type: KillProcessTask)
```

but am getting below exception

***> Could not get unknown property 'SpawnProcessTask' for root project 'example-api' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.***

please someone please suggest on this

Comment: what? clear your post

Comment: @Edwin , not getting your comment .

Comment: revise your post - is not understandable!

Comment: your integration task need to depend on the app running.

Comment: Not enough info in your post, but if your `run` task is a bootRun type task, then it doesn't complete until the application terminates, so whatever depends on it will not run until it stops. At which point your tests obviously won't run. You need to fork application execution and allow sufficient time for it to start before kicking off the tests.

Comment: @Strelok , the application for which i am writing integration tests is Spring boot application 

task integration(type: Test, description: 'Runs the integration tests.', group: 'Verification') {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

this is my integration task , so can you suggest how to add configuration , so that spring boot app will up and run before integration tests start execuitng

Comment: @Strelok  i use gradle built-in    run task to start the application , i even added below 

integration.dependsOn appRun
integration.mustRunAfter appRun

application started and stay their only , integration task is not running , can help me on this

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different approach: start and stop your application from your test framework. Test frameworks support setup and cleanup steps for your test suite (e.g. `BeforeClass` and `AfterClass` in JUnit), start the application in the setup step and stop it in the cleanup step. This approach will make your tests more self-contained, their success/failure will not depend on factors outside the test code.

Even if you prefer to run the application outside the test framework, I suggest wrapping this logic (i.e. starting the app, running the tests, stopping the app) in a Java class, and executing this class from Gradle via a task of type `JavaExec`. It will be much more clear than handling all this via Gradle tasks.

Finally, if you still insist on Gradle tasks, it's like the commenters said: the "run" task probably blocks execution while the app is running. Tha only sane way to handle this is to have a task that starts the app in the background, and another that stops it after the tests finished (use `finalizedBy`).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare that the integration test task needs to depend on your app run task.

`appRun` is just an example please use the name of the task that is the precursor for the integration test.

```
integration.dependsOn appRun
integration.mustRunAfter appRun
```

Also, it might be like your app is running and blocking the progress of your Gradle build, does the build actually finish or it just hangs until the app stops running?

Comment: I have that question. I'm trying to run "gulp watch" in dependsOn but it seems that is blocking the progress of gradle. Any suggestion?